# Snowflake call stored procedure with parameters from another stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to call a stored proc with parameters from another stored procedure and I think I'm messing up the quotes and backticks. The procedure I'm trying to call will log the steps of a chained set of tasks, so I can better track the task progress.

```
var create_temp_table_sql_cmd = `set batch_id = (select MD5_NUMBER_LOWER64(current_timestamp))`

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
     sqlText: create_temp_table_sql_cmd
     }
  );
var res = stmt.execute();

var create_temp_table_sql_cmd = `CALL log_stored_procedure(`'raw.silver'`, ` + $batch_id + `, `load_customer_visits`, `'load_customer_visit_events'`, `'step1 - load customer visit events table'`, `'log_init'`);`

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
     sqlText: create_temp_table_sql_cmd
     }
  );
var res = stmt.execute();
```

The error I get is: Unexepected string

Comment: You should only need a single set of back ticks wrapping the entire statement

Answer (score 2):

As Dean said:

```
var create_temp_table_sql_cmd = `set batch_id = (select MD5_NUMBER_LOWER64(current_timestamp))`

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
     sqlText: create_temp_table_sql_cmd
     }
  );
var res = stmt.execute();

var create_temp_table_sql_cmd = `CALL log_stored_procedure('raw.silver', $batch_id, 'load_customer_visits', 'load_customer_visit_events', 'step1 - load customer visit events table', 'log_init');`;

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
     sqlText: create_temp_table_sql_cmd
     }
  );
var res = stmt.execute();
```

btw, you can merge these two queries:

```
var create_temp_table_sql_cmd = `CALL log_stored_procedure('raw.silver', MD5_NUMBER_LOWER64(current_timestamp), 'load_customer_visits', 'load_customer_visit_events', 'step1 - load customer visit events table', 'log_init');`;

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
     {
     sqlText: create_temp_table_sql_cmd
     }
  );
var res = stmt.execute();
```